# How to get full path of a folder from sdcard?

Tags: android, sd-card

I want to get all folders and sub folders of a sdcard.  For example, I created a folder name `tempfolder`.  If I want to get the full path of `tempfolder`, like `mnt/sdcard/folder/tempfolder`. If i don't know where the folder is stored in sdcard, but i know the name of a folder.

Is it possible to get the full path of a folder based on folder name. If any one knows the solution, please help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do the next thing:

```
    //get the path of the sdcard and enter all the files to an array file
        File[] file = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().listFiles();  


        for (File f : file)
        {
            if (f.isDirectory()) { 
                 file[] innerFiles = f.listFiles();

                 for(int i=0; i< innerFiles.length;i++){
                   Log.i("Name", innerFiles[i].getPath() + "");
                 }
        }

            if (f.isFile()) { ... do stuff }
        }
```

Comment: hi,it gives like mnt/sdcard/DCIM.but ieant to later DCIM like..mnt/sdcard/DCIM/Camera or mnt/sdcard/DCIM/100MEDIA.If know how to get this please help me:Thanq

Comment: Thanq verymuch dude,it helps me.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `FileFilter` for seaching all the directory from root.

```
    String dirName= "mnt/sdcard/";

    File dir = new File(dirName);

    File[] files = (new File(dirName)).listFiles();

    // This filter only returns directories
    FileFilter dirFilter = new FileFilter() {
        public boolean accept(File dir) {
            return dir.isDirectory();
        }
    };

    files = dir.listFiles(dirFilter);

    for (int i=0; i<files.length; i++) {
        if(files[i].getAbsolutePath().contains("tempfolder"))
          System.out.println("directory path : " + files[i].getAbsolutePath());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

please Check out this. I think it help you.

```
    File file[] = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().listFiles();  


    for (File f : file)
    {
        if (f.isDirectory()) { 

            Log.i("Name", f.getPath()+"");
        }
    }
```

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Try this code:

```
for (File file : folder.listFiles()) {
    if (file.isFile()) {
       Log.v("Folders on the sd card are:  ", folder.getName() + " in path " + folder.getAbsolutePath());
    }
```

Comment: @kiran Please, nobody is working here for you and **Stackoverflow is not code repository**.